# NPM install use built package for ARM processor (Sentry)

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, sentry

I'm on a Raspberry pi 4. In my `package.json` I have:

```
"@sentry/browser": "^5.19.2",
"@sentry/node": "^5.19.2",
```

When I attempt to execute `npm i` with an ARM processor it won't build. It gives the error

> Error: Command failed: /var/www/website/node_modules/@sentry/cli/sentry-cli --version
> /var/www/website/node_modules/@sentry/cli/sentry-cli: 1: ELF: not found
> /var/www/website/node_modules/@sentry/cli/sentry-cli: 2: Syntax error: ")" unexpected

This is due to the fact that `sentry-cli` does not have an ARM build. Here is a [GitHub issue](https://github.com/getsentry/sentry-cli/issues/592) on that fact and the way you can build `sentry-cli` on your own. So I have built it and have the binary in my user folder. But I have no idea how to get it to look for that binary when run `npm i`

I tried to provide the path to my binary folder in the dependencies array, but that doesn't work since it's not a package and doesn't have its own package.json file. Any idea on how to install Sentry on an ARM?